# Почему не рекомендуется использовать Thread.Resume() и Thread.Suspend()?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, потоки-данных, .net

Почему не рекомендуется использовать Thread.Resume() и Thread.Suspend()?

Comment: Не в принципе "не рекомендуется", а не рекомендуется для останова-возобновления процесса, который реализует поток. Это связано с тем, что Suspend может приостановить поток в "неподходящем месте", возобновление с которого может привести к различным ошибкам доступа.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Не рекомендуется их использовать неверно.

Но если по правилам, то Thered.Resume() должен вызывать другой тред (по понятным причинам, тред не может сам себя снять с паузы), а вот Thered.Suspend() должен вызывать тред только у себя самого. У другого треда вызывать этот метод нельзя, так как непонятно, где именно он остановится.

А не рекомендуют их, потому что есть много хороших и разных способов синхронизации: критические секции, мютексы, события, семафоры и так далее.

Comment: Вы так и не ответили, как "неверно" и почему же не рекомендуют. ".. а не рекомендуют ходить по стройке без каски, потому что есть много хороших и разных способов защитить голову шлемы, зонтики, и т.п."

Comment: Перефразирую специально для тех, кто считает, что я не ответил. Можно сказать так, что Resume - это зеленый свет светофора, а Suspend - это педаль тормоза. другой тред - это другой человек, не водитель. И если кто то другой будет нажимать тормоз, то может быть все что угодно.

Answer (score 6):

Взято [**отсюда**](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) - раздел [**`#`Suspend and Resume:**](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Suspend_and_Resume)

> - From `.NET 2.0`, `Suspend` and `Resume` have been deprecated, their use discouraged because of the danger inherent in **arbitrarily suspending another thread.** If a thread holding a lock on a critical resource is suspended, the whole application (or computer) can deadlock.
> - This is far more dangerous than calling `Abort` — which results in any such locks being released (at least theoretically) by virtue of code in `finally` blocks.

Comment: Хуже того, вы _не можете_ предсказать, не держит ли текущий поток блокировку. Например, он может быть в нативном коде и держать в этот самый момент блокировку кучи -- считайте, что ваш процесс умер.